# share point workflow deployment

Tags: sharepoint

Hello
 I'm new in workflows.
 I have Created a simple workflow, that send email 
 on an event off add row to sharepoint list,i create the workflow with
 sharepoint desinger Wizard and click finish in the Wizard

is in this stage i Should see the workflow in -
 Site Settings \ Galleries \ Workflows

Comment: can you retype you question with some punctuation... the question is not comprehensible as this.

Comment: Why should anyone answer you, if you don't put any effort in writing your question and then never accept an answer?

Comment: Now you have a complete answer to the question, mark it as such. This helps other people identify solutions to problems that they too might be experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a Workflow in SPD it is only available for the list you specified in the Workflow Designer. You can get to it via the List Settings menu.
If you want a wider deployment for you workflow you must build it with Visual Studio and deploy it to the back-end server using a feature (I think).

Comment: now my problam with the workflow, is that it not starts Automatic on a row insert. the work flow only start if i goto the row and exec the workflow

Comment: This is achieved on the first screen of the Workflow Designer, where you selected the list that it would be associated with.

Comment: i did check the checkbox Automatically start this workflow when a new item is created ,in the first screen of the Workflow Designer but it is not start Automatic.

Comment: Double check that the box is checked. Also check to see if your workflow will start automatically when an item is modified. If your workflow doesn't start in either case then I think you need to start a new question.

Answer (score 0):

To make the workflow available in the gallery, I believe it needs to be created as a reusable workflow and you will find it under ***Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Site Collection Administration -> Workflows***